# Correctly typing a vuex getter's getters parameter

Tags: typescript, vuex

How would I correctly type a vuex getter which refers to other getters? For example:

```js
import { GetterTree } from 'vuex';

class State {
    foo: string[] = [];
}

const getters = <GetterTree<State, any>>{
    bar: state => state.foo.filter(...something...),
    baz: (state, getters) => getters.bar.filter(...something else...)
}
```

Here the `getters` parameter of `getters.baz` is typed as `any` by the `vuex` definition. It would be nice if it could be typed as `{ bar: string[] }` implicitly based on the `const getters` declaration, without having to declare it twice as an interface or such. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: please provide code examples with valid syntax

Comment: You mean the `...something...` placeholders…?

Comment: I mean this `<GetterTree<State, any>>{`.

Comment: That… *is…* valid…?

Comment: Ok, I see. It is assertion.

Answer (score 0):

Let's take a look on `GetterTree` interface:

```js
export interface GetterTree<S, R> {
  [key: string]: Getter<S, R>;
}
```

Hence, `state => state.foo.filter(...something...)` corresponds to `Getter<S, R>`.

Unfortunatelly, second argument `getters` is not generic and typed by the default as `any`:

```js
export type Getter<S, R> = (state: S, getters: any, rootState: R, rootGetters: any) => any;
```

Generic parameter `R` from the `GetterTree` corresponds to `rootState` which is not interesting for us.

I see two options.

**First - the easiest.**

Just add explicit type to the second argument:

```js
const getters: GetterTree<State, any> = {
  bar: state => state.foo.filter(e => e.length > 1),
  baz: (state, getters: { bar: string[] }) => getters.bar
}
```

Second one, is to overwrite  the `GetterTree` built in utility type.

```js
import { GetterTree, Getter } from 'vuex';

class State {
  foo: string[] = [];
}

type CustomGetter<T extends Getter<any, any>, Getters> =
  T extends (state: infer State, getters: infer _, rootState: infer RootState, rootGetters: infer RootGetters) => any
  ? (state: State, getters: Getters, rootState: RootState, rootGetters: RootGetters) => any
  : never

type CustomGetterTree<T extends GetterTree<any, any>, Getters> = T extends GetterTree<infer S, infer R> ? {
  [key: string]: CustomGetter<Getter<S, R>, Getters>;

} : never

const getters: CustomGetterTree<GetterTree<State, any>, { bar: string[] }> = {
  bar: state => state.foo.filter(e => e.length > 1),
  baz: (state, getters /** {  bar: string[];} */) => getters.bar
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgcQKYxqqAVKrUA0K6mUcAvnAGZQQhwDkAbgK6oAeDA3AFA8DGAGwCGAZ1FwAyjGGZEPONQgQAXHFEwowAHYBzANoBdOAF44R3uT4wAnmFRwAwiw100GLAB5scDpm0AJhLupJ7C2jZE4TYAfEQhWKIxpgpwPn6ogRIAFBqyqGo6VFhSMphEuiSJhdrFZAD6RLQQMNL5NXVwAErKrWWEcM0wCVCiHSU9LSOiAJSmydGpAPxwuf1qbeVwlR6jatNNvZsF3Uf9h1NVe6eXu7PzcIuKatqoTFjWdg7OriAjuPhvL52P4gsRdgDUGEIlEInFwaQkqY0sDQcErpDPEUSpIiNiyF1kisEKl9ABrVA2NQaLR6QxqH4wNxXTwjTy47rw6YxXg8SgvN4fAQQbQabZXMZOFxMv4YvBQ-7y9nnR5wohIABGwig1M0OgMxnIyTMJMUWp16n6DzymAAdFRlPbgIJSNkHCZkqhbYJMroYAALODJACMMwIqS1AC81Gt8hUJXAAPQAKmTiDN2t1tINXEoycTcw94rutvNfJ4QA)

Comment: That _does_ require a duplicate declaration of `{ bar: string[] }` in `CustomGetterTree<...>`, right? Which would become rather unwieldy for a large number of getters. I was afraid of that, I'm not seeing a better option either… Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunatelly I dont see either. They did not provide an extra generic argument for `getters`. Maybe it worth creating PR?

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** if using Vue3 and TypeScript with Vuex, I'd switch to [pinia](https://pinia.vuejs.org/) which seems to come with decent type safety. Worked for me, at least.

Dunno if it's worth considering a different approach. I like to try and infer the return type of a getter using a helper function. I find it saves me on the complex type definitions although it incurs a bit of repetition on the keys used to reference a getter.

```
const getters = {
    gridHeight(): number {
        return 32;
    },
    message(): string {
        return 'hello ';
    },
};
const store = createStore<State>({ getters });

type ReturnOfGetter<T> = T extends (state: infer _, getters: infer _, rootState: infer _, rootGetters: infer _) => infer Return
    ? Return                                                                                                                          
    : never;

export function useGetter<K extends keyof typeof getters>(key: K): ReturnOfGetter<typeof getters[K]> {
    return store.getters[key];                                                                                           
};
```

This allows for access like so:

```
const gridHeight = useGetter<'gridHeight'>('gridHeight');
const message = useGetter<'message'>('message');
```