# Typing a Vuex Method-Style Getter

Tags: javascript, typescript, vuex

I'm trying to understand how I can properly type a [Vuex Method-Style getter](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html#method-style-access).  Here's a [Fiddle](https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-river-gmj01k?file=/src/store.ts), and the code:

```
interface IData {
    name: string;
}

type IGetters = {
    data(getters: IGetters): IData;
    getDataByKey: (getters: IGetters) => (name: string) => string;
    getName(getters: IGetters): string;
}

const getters: IGetters = {
    data(getters) {
        return {
            name: 'Hello'
        };
    },
    getDataByKey: (getters) => (name) => {
        return getters.data[name as keyof typeof getters.data];
    },
    getName(getters) {
        return getters.getDataByKey('name');
    }
}
```

The issue I'm having is `getName`.  When invoking `getDataByKey`, TS throws TS-2345 `Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'IGetters'.`  To me, it seems like it thinks I need to call the function that has `(getters)` as the params, but that's not how this works in Vuex.

I saw this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68996232/1253609), and I tried to implement what was done, but it didn't work, so I'm pretty sure I didn't implement it properly.  Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: `getters.getDataByKey(getters)('name');`

Comment: > To me, it seems like it thinks I need to call the function that has (getters) as the params 

Yes, this is exactly what you have to do. TypeScript is working as intended here.

Why is `getters` a parameter of that function in the first place?

Comment: @jered Yeah, I was hoping to remove Vuex from this example, but it seems like it's probably the reason why I'm getting the TS error.  The point of Vuex getters is that they're treated as computed properties, not like a function, so you actually would invoke it by doing `getters.data`, and that'd return the object, no need to pass `getters`, as Vuex does that for you.

Comment: Is there an issue with doing `getters.getDataByKey(getters)('name');`?

Comment: @jered, yes, I've updated the Fiddle to be an actual Vuex example now.  Think of Vuex getters like a [JS getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like per Vuex's definition of a [getter](https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/blob/main/types/index.d.ts#L124) (`export type Getter<S, R> = (state: S, getters: any, rootState: R, rootGetters: any) => any;`), they use `any` to get around this issue, which isn't ideal, but it's at least an answer.  My `IGetters` definition would turn into:

```
type IGetters = {
  data(state: State, getters: any): IData;
  getDataByKey: (state: State, getters: any) => (name: string) => string;
  getName(state: State, getters: any): string;
};
```